# Make element move up and down on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have three columns on a website, all three with titles and related paragraphs of text. There is a gray box being used as a background for the text, but I need the gray box to glide up and cover both the paragraph text and the column title.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="span3 lower-columns" id="lower-col-left" style="padding-top:10px;">
        Rewards
        <p class="lower-col-text">placeholder text placeholder text placeholder text placeholder text placeholder text placeholder text placeholder text placeholder text</p>
        </div>
      <div class="span3 lower-columns" id="lower-col-mid">
        Schedule an Installation
        <p class="lower-col-text" style="padding-top:30px;">placeholder text placeholder text placeholder text placeholder text placeholder text placeholder text placeholder text placeholder text</p>
        </div>
      <div class="span3 lower-columns" id="lower-col-right" style="padding-top:10px;">
        Contact Us
        <p class="lower-col-text">placeholder text placeholder text placeholder text placeholder text placeholder text placeholder text placeholder text placeholder text</p>
        </div>

     </div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.span3.lower-columns {
    height: 370px;
    text-align:center;
    width: 280px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    font-size: 28px;
    background-image: url('/img/lower-col-bg2.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 70px;
    background-size: 290px 290px;
```

}

Here's what it looks like (non-hover): 
[image]

Here's the background image:

[image]

I'd rather use just CSS, but not opposed to using jQuery.

Thanks!!!!

**EDIT: I figured it out on my own, but it won't let me answer my own question. Here's the CSS in case anyone is wondering:**

```
.span3.lower-columns {
  height: 370px;
  text-align:center;
  width: 280px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 28px;
  background-image: url('/img/lower-col-bg2.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-y: 70px;
  background-size: 290px 290px;
  position: relative;
}
 .span3.lower-columns:hover {
  background-position-y: 0px;
  transition: .65s;
}
```

Comment: Show us an image of what you want it to look like on hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own. Here's the CSS in case anyone is wondering:

```
.span3.lower-columns {
  height: 370px;
  text-align:center;
  width: 280px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 28px;
  background-image: url('/img/lower-col-bg2.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-y: 70px;
  background-size: 290px 290px;
  position: relative;
}
 .span3.lower-columns:hover {
  background-position-y: 0px;
  transition: .65s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use :hover.

```
.span3.lower-columns:hover {
  background-image: url('/img/lower-col-bg2.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-y: 0px;
}
```

Of course that's assuming you want it underneath the title, not that you want to hide the text and title with the gray box. If you do (want to hide the text with the gray box), you can either use a separate img element with the z-index property or a pseudo-element of the right size and color (with :after).

Answer (score 0):

If it is a background image, it will go behind whatever text you place on top of it. You would have to create a :hover and move the position of the background to make it reside where the text is. The problem then lies for you in how to get rid of the text? You can't unless you

a: make an image with the text erased
b: have an image in the div that you can place over using a z-index

```
.span3.lower-columns:hover {
    height: 370px;
    text-align:center;
    width: 280px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    font-size: 28px;
    background-image: url('/img/lower-col-bg2.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 00px;
    background-size: 290px 290px;

}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, I actually just figured it out on my own, but it won't let me answer my own question.